# How To Call Facebook Interstitial Ad Again In Case It Returns No Fill?

Tags: ads, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

I am having a problem.

Please tell me that how can i call facebook audience network Interstitial ad again in case it returned a no-fill. Eg: If someone downloads a picture from my app then i want to show him/her an ad. I tried implementing ads but sometimes it is showing ads and maximum times it does not. So how can i call this ad again and again until it returns me a filled ad.

```
It is easy to do the same in Admob ads but i want to use Facebook Audience Network Ads. Please Help Me
```

Answer (score 0):

if the user doesn't have a Facebook id on your phone then the FB audience gives an error no fill.

Run your app on your original device then this problem goes away